Facebook Conversion API is recording Conversion, but no attribution to ads
I have a conversion API set up, which seems to have good enough amount of parameters, it is connected to an ad set:


I am missing the following events, which don't seem to be that important:

My ads are showing 0 conversions:

I am sure that the ads deliver results, because I have been running the same ads for almost 10 years and I notice when my ads are paused and there are no other sources of conversions.
There should be thousands of conversions attributed to the ads, but I see 0.
Is the FBC parameter that important? Shouldn't I see at least some conversions? I did check dataset numbers etc, its all consistent.

I just found an answer somewhere and it seems to resolve the issue for me:
Apparently, if you deduplicate, usually the Pixel event is kept while the Conversions API event is discarded. If the Pixel event for some reason can't be used for attribution, as a result there is no attribution.
What I did is pausing the purchase pixel event in GTM and testing (clicking on the ad link and placing order) and suddenly this conversion was in fact attributed. https://www.ablecdp.com/blog/two-reasons-why-your-facebook-conversions-api-integration-doesnt-work
I'll be keeping an eye out on this actually solving the issue for good, but hopefully this will fix it for you as well.

Thanks, I read the post. In my case I don't have anything browser based, I only send events in conversion api. And I don't have GTM. So not sure what to do?
